# Angular2 Spring Authentication

Tags: spring, angular

I have separate Angular2 Client and Spring hosted servers.
My Angular2 application is able to call rest call of the spring.
But, I am facing few difficulties to do CSRF authentication with Spring.

```
main.ts:

    import { CsrfBaseRequestOptions } from './app/shared';

    bootstrap(AppComponent, [
      ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
      HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      ...
      provide(RequestOptions, { useClass: CsrfBaseRequestOptions })
    ]);
    XhrBaseRequestOptions:

    @Injectable()
    export class XhrBaseRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {

      constructor() {
        super();

        this.headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
      }

    }
    CsrfBaseRequestOptions:

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { XhrBaseRequestOptions } from './xhr-base-request-options';

    @Injectable()
    export class CsrfBaseRequestOptions extends XhrBaseRequestOptions {

      constructor() {
        super();

        let csrfToken = this.getCsrfToken('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
        if (csrfToken) {
          this.headers.append('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken);
        }
      }

      getCsrfToken(tokenName:string):string {
        let tokenNameEQ = tokenName + '=';
        let ck = document.cookie;
        let ca = ck.split(';');

        for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
          let c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
          if (c.indexOf(tokenNameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(tokenNameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
      }

    }

    index.ts

    onSubmit(event, username, password) {
            this.headers = new Headers();
            this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
            let body = JSON.stringify({username, password});
            this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/EEP/test', body, { headers: this.headers })
                .subscribe((res) => this.token = res.json())


        }
```

hear Nothing is happening.

THanks in advance if you help me to call the Spring  ..

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use the Automatic XSRF handling of Angular2 available from RC2. This is done under the hood by the `XSRFHandler` class and don't need to add explicitly the cookie to the request.

See these links:

- http://5thingsangular.github.io/2016/05/30/issue-6.html
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8898

Comment: CookieXSRFStrategy and XSRFHandler is not available in my node_modules under @angular/http package. So ide giving compilation error in ts file at import statement import {HTTP_PROVIDERS,XSRFHandler, CookieXSRFHandler} from '@angular/http'

Comment: Both classes are located in the `xhr_backend.ts` file. See this link: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L184. Which Angular2 version do you use?

Comment: XSRFHandler is missing in xhr_backend.ts ..I found XSRFStrategy ?..Is it the same file ?

Comment: Hi Thierry, I have implemented all the changes which have suggested actually my project was rc1 I have build to rc4 by package.json changes..now I have implemented the HTTP_PROVIDERS as CookieXSRFStrategy >>>>>>   HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    {
        provide: XSRFStrategy,
        useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('MY-XSRF-COOKIE-NAME', 'MY-XSRF-HEADER-NAME')
    },ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy,
    {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}), PersonService]);

Comment: But the issue is in Posting code spring server is not getting hit >>>>>>>>>>  onSubmit(event, username, password) {
        var json = JSON.stringify({
            username: username, password: password
        });

        this.headers = new CookieXSRFStrategy();
        let body = JSON.stringify({username,password});
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
        this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/EEP/test', body, options)
            .subscribe((res) => this.token = res.json())
    }      ...please suggest..THANKS !!